# Get data for current month using Linq - VB

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have the following code which is listing the top 3 'names' in descending order with a count of how many records that 'name' appears in in the table. This is working ok.

```
Dim top3 = From s In dc.Suggestions
               Group By Name = s.name
               Into t3 = Group, Count()
               Order By Count Descending
               Take 3
```

I want to amend this so that it will only get a count of the number of records each 'name' appears in for the current month. I can use s.dateRaised to get the date of the record but i'm not entirely sure how to write the code to get only the current month's records?

Comment: `where Month(s.dateRaised) = Month(DateTime.Now)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a slight modification on Karl's answer.  I like this one a little better because his answer will not include anything with a `dateRaised` value during the last minute of the last day of the month.

```
Dim CurrentYear As Integer = DateTime.Today.Year
Dim CurrentMonth As Integer = DateTime.Today.Month

Dim startOfCurrentMonthDate As New DateTime(CurrentYear, CurrentMonth, 1)
Dim startOfNextMonthDate As DateTime = startOfCurrentMonthDate.AddMonths(1)

Dim top3 = From s In dc.Suggestions
           Where s.dateRaised >= startOfCurrentMonthDate AndAlso
                 s.dateRaised < startOfNextMonthDate 
           Group By Name = s.name
           Into t3 = Group, Count()
           Order By Count Descending
           Take 3
```

Comment: Thanks Douglas, one small problem. The dateRaised is of data type nvarchar so I'm getting the error 'The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value'

Comment: In that case, use `CDate`, `DateTime.Parse`, or `Convert.ToDateTime` to change it to a datetime.

Answer (score 1):

First, get the beginning and end of the current month, like this:

```
Dim CurrentYear As Integer = DateTime.Today.Year
Dim CurrentMonth As Integer = DateTime.Today.Month

Dim startOfCurrentMonthDate As New DateTime(CurrentYear, CurrentMonth, 1)
Dim endOfCurrentMonthDate As DateTime = startDate.AddMonths(1).AddMinutes(-1)
```

Now, you need to use the start and end dates in your `Where`, like this:

```
Dim top3 = From s In dc.Suggestions
           Where s.dateRaised >= startOfCurrentMonthDate And
                 s.dateRaised <= endOfCurrentMonthDate
           Group By Name = s.name
           Into t3 = Group, Count()
           Order By Count Descending
           Take 3
```

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't use `startDate.AddMonths(1).AddTicks(-1)` or simply `startDate.AddMonths(1)` and a less-than check?